# jQuery Design Pattern for Updating Selectors When the HTML Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some advice on a making my jQuery selectors more configurable. For example, given the following HTML generated by PHP:

```
<ul id="my-list">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

And a bit of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#my-list li", function() {
        alert("You clicked " + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

So far so good, but then one day the designer comes along and renames the id "my-list" to "list-of-numbers", and the javascript stops working. Currently the solution is *remembering* to grep through the code for any references to "my-list", but that's very faulty. Is there a jQuery design pattern for making the selectors configurable?

Comment: You can use PHP variable as the `<ul>` ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be called 'selector selection.' You can define a set of variables that have the selectors in them as a solution:

```
var selectors = { myLi: "#my-list li",
                  myUl: "#my-div ul" };
```

Then you can simply do an object lookup to get the selector:

```
$(selectors.myLi);
```

This has the advantage of being readable and dynamic; however, in your example scenario where someone changes the `ID`, this would not be very helpful unless it's explicitly noted somewhere in your code that changes are necessary.

You might want to consider doing some [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and using custom [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to define roles.

Comment: Just an FYI, as of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: @mellowsoon You're right, of course. I was more trying to refer to the [concept of event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) rather than jQuery's `.delegate()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Define a set of selectors at the beginning of your JS-Code (don't forget to add a comment for what you use it):

```
var selectors = {
  'listSelector':'#my-list li' /* DESC */,
  'nextSelector': '.whatever'
}
```

and use them in your queries:

```
 $(document).on("click", selectors.listSelector, function() {
    alert("You clicked " + $(this).text());
 });
```